# Scala pass a generic function into another generic function confusion

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

I'm implementing the List type in Scala when following a book.

Here's the definition of my List type:

```
sealed trait List[+A]

case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
```

All the later mentioned functions are defined in the companion object List in the same file

```
object List
```

I wrote `foldLeft` and `foldRight` as the following

```
def foldLeft[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = l match {
    case Nil => z
    case Cons(x, xs) => foldLeft(xs, f(z, x))(f)
}

def foldRight[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = l match {
    case Nil => z
    case Cons(x, xs) => f(x, foldRight(xs, z)(f))
}
```

There's an exercise on the book, which is to implement `foldLeft` using `foldRight`. Here's my initial implementation

```
def foldLeftWithRight[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
    foldRight(l, z)((a: A, b: B) => f(b, a))
}
```

Then I think I should write another function to do the reverse arguments if I'm to implement `foldRight` using `foldLeft`. As follows:

```
def reverseArgs[A,B](f: (A, B) => B): (B, A) => B = {
    (b: B, a: A) => f(a, b)
}
```

So I changed code of `foldLeftWithRight` to the following:

```
def foldLeftWithRight[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
    foldRight(l, z)(reverseArgs(f))
}
```

And IntelliJ is complaining about `reverseArgs(f)`:

> Type mismatch: expected (A, B) => B, actual (B, B) => B

When I try to compile the code, the error is the following:

```
Error:(21, 37) type mismatch;
    found   : (B, A) => B
    required: (B, Any) => Any
        foldRight(l, z)(reverseArgs(f))
```

An interesting observation is that when I use the `reverseArgs` on `foldRightWithLeft`, there's no problem at all:

```
def foldRightWithLeft[A,B](l: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = {
    foldLeft(l, z)(reverseArgs(f))
}
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rename type parameters of your `reverseArgs` function to `X` and `Y`, you'll get something like

```
def reverseArgs[X ,Y](f: (X, Y) => Y): (Y, X) => Y = ???
```

Type of `f` in `foldLeftWithRight` is `(B, A) => B`. Passing that to `reverseArgs` means that:

```
X = B
Y = A
Y = B
```

I guess Intellij infers from here that A = B and this is why it's complaining that `(B, B) => B` isn't `(A, B) => B`. Scalac decides that Y = Any instead, because it's the least upper bound of two potentially unrelated types.

---

Good solution here is to generalize more. Return type of reversed function does not have to be one of parameter types, so you can introduce another generic type for that:

```
def reverseArgs[X ,Y, Z](f: (X, Y) => Z): (Y, X) => Z = {
    (b: Y, a: X) => f(a, b)
}
```